# Como agrupar por fecha o número del mes en el mismo campo en sql server

Tags: sql

Tengo un procedimiento sencillo que recibe 3 parametros (`@desde as date`, `@hasta as date`, `@agrupa as int`) necesito que si `@agrupa=0` agrupe el resultado por dias y si `@agrupa=1` agrupe el resultado por mes.

```
SELECT case when @agrupa =0 then DOC_CFECHA
    else MONTH(DOC_CFECHA) end as fecha
    ,total= sum(cantidad)
FROM documentos
WHERE DOC_CFECHA between @desde and @hasta 
group by case when @agrupa=0 then DOC_CFECHA else MONTH(DOC_CFECHA) end
```

Si mando @agrupa en 0 no hay ningún problema, el procedimiento funciona, pero si le envío el 1 para agrupar por mes el resultado de la columna se convierte a formato de fecha así: **1900-01-02 00:00:00.000** en lugar de mostrar el numero del mes.

Intento no usar **IF** para escribir 2 sentencias ni menos escribir 2 procedimientos separados.
Alguna idea como hacerlo en la misma sentencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder devolver una sentencia con los mismos datos agrupados, debes devolver la columna con el mismo tipo de dato.

```
Create table dbo.documentos (Doc_CFecha datetime, cantidad int);

go
insert into dbo.documentos (Doc_CFecha, cantidad)
values
('20201001',2),
('20201101',4),
('20201101',5),
('20201102',6),
('20201001',3),
('20201003',4),
('20201001',1),
('20201101',2),
('20201001',2);
go
```

Por ejemplo, como varchar

```
Declare @AGRUPA int = 0;
declare @DESDE datetime = '19000101';
declare @HASTA datetime = '21000101';

SELECT case
            when @AGRUPA = 0 then Convert(varchar(30), doc_cfecha, 120)
            else cast(MONTH(DOC_CFECHA) as varchar(30))
       end as fecha
     , sum(cantidad) as Total
       FROM dbo.documentos
       WHERE DOC_CFECHA between @DESDE and @HASTA
       group by case
                     when @AGRUPA = 0 then Convert(varchar(30), doc_cfecha, 120)
                     else cast(MONTH(DOC_CFECHA) as varchar(30))
                end;
```

[image: Resultado 0]

```
Declare @AGRUPA int = 1;
declare @DESDE datetime = '19000101';
declare @HASTA datetime = '21000101';

SELECT case
            when @AGRUPA = 0 then Convert(varchar(30), doc_cfecha, 120)
            else cast(MONTH(DOC_CFECHA) as varchar(30))
       end as fecha
     , sum(cantidad) as Total
       FROM dbo.documentos
       WHERE DOC_CFECHA between @DESDE and @HASTA
       group by case
                     when @AGRUPA = 0 then Convert(varchar(30), doc_cfecha, 120)
                     else cast(MONTH(DOC_CFECHA) as varchar(30))
                end;
```

[image: Resultado 1]

Comment: Excelente Javi fer2, mil gracias...!!